# Algorithm for regular expressions - combinations on or

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm

I'm developing a C++ application to first parse regular expression strings and then perform some calculations with it. Are there any existing algorithms that can that output the number N of strings of length L that can be recognized by a given regex such as `(a|ab)* | (aa|bb)*`? Or is there a mathematical formula I can use such as one involving factorials? I just want to get the number N of strings that can be recognized by such regex phrases for a given number L. Example for `(a|ab)*` how many strings of length 5 (L) can be recognized by the regex. I think the answer would be 5. But for high numbers of L I was wondering if there are any algorithms or math expressions that can calculate that.

Comment: The number of strings matched by `(something)*`? Seriously? It's infinite.

Comment: you need to update your regex or give examples of actual strings, you may have misunderstood the pattern match.

Comment: @ergonaut Are you talking to me or te7? What would it help if te7 gives us actual strings?

Comment: @devianfan perhaps he means (a|ab)? otherwise you are right, the algorithm would dump out a, aa, aaa, aaaa.. and never get to the 'ab's.

Comment: I just want to get the number N of strings that can be recognized by such regex phrases for a given number L. Example for (a|ab)* how many strings of length 5 (L) can be recognized by the regex. I think the answer would be 5. But for high numbers of L I was wondering if there are any algorithms or math expressions that can calculate that. The asterisks are intentional.

Comment: @te7 Please add that your question (that there is a target string length).

Comment: @te7 Btw., your example is not 5, but 8.

Comment: @te7: Are you looking for *any* algorithm or an *efficient* algorithm? If you're looking for a computability result then all you need to do is enumerate all possible strings of your desired length and then run the regex against them...

Comment: Thanks for that correction. Did you use math to get 8 or did you just work it out on paper?

Comment: I'm looking for an efficient algorithm.

Comment: If anyone wants to try solving this, the same problem is a challenge on hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-strings

Comment: @deviantfan for a finite `L` (max length of a string) the answer is far unimaginably smaller 
 than `infinite`.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an efficient algorithm based on matrix exponentiation that you can use to compute these numbers.

I'm only going to give a high level description, not code.

1. First, you want to use a well-known equivalence from foundations of computer science, that a (simple) regular expression is equivalent to a finite state machine.

   (Recall that a finite state machine, is essentially a flow chart, in which from each node, there is a labeled edge for each letter in your alphabet to some particular other node (or maybe its a loop). Additionally, some subset of the states is called the "Accept Set", and some particular state in the flow chart is the start state. A string is said to induce a path in the finite state machine, by starting in the start state and following the labelled edges in succession. The machine `accepts` a string if the final state is in the accept set, and `rejects` a string otherwise.
   A classical construction shows that from any regular expression we can construct a finite state machine of similar size, and from any finite state machine we can construct a regular expression of similar size. Any language (subset of all finite strings) which corresponds to a regular expression is called "regular" and a language is regular if and only if it corresponds to a finite state machine.)

   For example, if I have an alphabet `{a,b,c}`, and the regular expression `(a|b)*`, it corresponds to a machine with two states. The start state has a loop labelled `a`, a loop labelled `b`, and an arrow labelled `c` to the second state. The second state has three loops to itself, so you get trapped if you go there. The accept set contains only the start state.

   The first step of your program is to convert a regular expression to a corresponding finite state machine. (It might be that some existing regex library already does this basically, I think that PCRE might, although I'm not sure.)
2. Given a finite state machine, I want to construct a corresponding stochastic matrix. In this matrix, we have a row for each state, and a column for each state, and each entry is a probability. The probability `p_{i,j}` at entry `(i,j)`, is equal to the probability that if I'm at state `i`, and I read a random letter, I go to state `j` next. So for the example I gave, the matrix is

   [ 2/3  1/3 ]
   [   0    1 ]
3. If you want to know about strings of length `k`, then using matrix exponentiation, compute the matrix `M^k` where `M` is the probability transition matrix above.
4. Finally, if `q` is the start state, add up all of the entries `M^k_{q, s}` for each state `s` in the accept set. The sum of these probabilities is exactly equal to the probability that a random string of length `k` is accepted by the regular expression. So, you can get the number of such strings by multipling by `N^k` where `N` is the number of letters in your alphabet.

I think the existence of this algorithm is not hard, but it's not trivial either, I once gave a harder version of this as an extra credit problem in a final exam in a theory of computation class. I don't know of any existing implementation of it, would be interested to know.

There is some significant speed-up that you get doing it this way over the naive method, when you use matrix exponentiation. That allows you to do it for large `k` quickly.

I don't know if there's a more efficient, approximate solution, it would be interesting. I guess that random sampling will always give you something but maybe there's some kind of spectral algorithm, based on doing singular value decomposition of the matrix `M` or something.

Note: If you actually want to implement it, I guess that you should not use floating point numbers, the matrix `M` should actually be a matrix of integers. Basically you would multiply it by `N` where `N` is the number of letters in your alphabet. And you would skip multiplying the sum by `N^k` later. I think it's easier to understand using probabilities, but in that version, `M^k_{i,j}` would just be counting `number of paths from i to j of length k`.

Note: As pointed out in the comments, this algorithm is polynomial in the number of bits of `k` for any fixed regular expression, so it's good even for large `k`. It's exponential in the worst case though in the size of the regular expression though -- to handle large and complicated regular expressions, you should use some kind of DFA minimization I guess if you want to use this method. For the simple regular expressions shown in the question, I think it should be fine.

Comment: Where do 1/3 and 2/3 come from? Are you assuming that b is twice as likely than a? (PCRE doesn't create FSMs. [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2) uses a memoised DFA algorithm, which avoids exponential DFA blowup. Flex and Ragel build real DFAs; Ragel has an XML output option which I've never looked at but it might be useful. Unlike Flex, Ragel does state minimization. Regex->DFA libraries are scattered around the 'net; some of them work.)

Comment: Sorry, I just fail at arithmetic. For some reason I thought there was a `c` i think, can't keep my examples straight. I changed the example now.

Comment: Cool. I'm not sure that the stochastic matrix helps understanding; personally, I'd just count the transitions from i->j (which is the same as computing the probability and multiplying by the alphabet size, since the transition probability is the number of symbols triggering that transition divided by the alphabet size). That ends up with your last paragraph, anyway. What makes this algorithm exponential (in the length of the regex) is that the DFA state count is worst-case exponential in the length of the regex. But normally, it should be fast enough. Anyway, I don't have a better one :)

Comment: @rici: thanks for pointing this out, I guess I forgot some details of the transformation. iirc, it's polynomial to go from regex to NFA (nondeterministic finite automata) and polynomial to go back from NFA to regex. But it's exponential to go from NFA to DFA (unavoidably). I don't know if there's a nice way to adapt the algorithm so that you can do something directly on an NFA transition matrix, it sounds a bit hopeful

Comment: I don't have enough maths reference to understand how (NM)^k will give the count of strings of length k? Some pointers would surely help?

Comment: @Biboswan there's a mention here in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers but it doesn't explain the idea in detail, i think course notes or a book on Algebraic Graph Theory will cover this though. Basically it comes out of taking the formula that defines matrix multiplication and expanding it to a big sum of terms. Then you have to observe that each term is a product of entries of A, and the entries of A are 0-1 valued, so the term is 1 iff every entry corresponds to an edge in A, and the term is 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Chris https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnssRe5DewE on Markov matrices also gives some light